# Filter periodical sharp spikes in experimental data

Tags: filtering

I have experimental data with periodic sharp artefact spikes, which mask the real signal that could be seen as several negative peaks in the first third part on the curve:

[image]

Is it possible somehow to filter these spikes? or at least significantly reduce them? Here is data set:

```
data = {{5.`, 2.41204`}, {10.`, 2.40477`}, {15.`, 2.40154`}, {20.`, 
2.4094`}, {25.`, 2.41592`}, {30.`, 2.40706`}, {35.`, 
2.41802`}, {40.`, 2.4171`}, {45.`, 2.40979`}, {50.`, 
2.4127`}, {55.`, 2.40254`}, {60.`, 2.40753`}, {65.`, 
2.41049`}, {70.`, 2.40521`}, {75.`, 2.40446`}, {80.`, 
2.40692`}, {85.`, 2.40509`}, {90.`, 2.40604`}, {95.`, 
2.40464`}, {100.`, 2.40448`}, {105.`, 2.41854`}, {110.`, 
2.41627`}, {115.`, 2.40941`}, {120.`, 2.40443`}, {125.`, 
2.39909`}, {130.`, 2.41194`}, {135.`, 2.40494`}, {140.`, 
2.40801`}, {145.`, 2.41532`}, {150.`, 2.41512`}, {155.`, 
2.41328`}, {160.`, 2.41383`}, {165.`, 2.40806`}, {170.`, 
2.3958`}, {175.`, 2.41296`}, {180.`, 2.41556`}, {185.`, 
2.40119`}, {190.`, 2.27056`}, {195.`, 2.51902`}, {200.`, 
2.41532`}, {205.`, 2.36206`}, {210.`, 2.37837`}, {215.`, 
2.38771`}, {220.`, 2.39959`}, {225.`, 2.40557`}, {230.`, 
2.40373`}, {235.`, 2.4045`}, {240.`, 2.39692`}, {245.`, 
2.38983`}, {250.`, 2.39646`}, {255.`, 2.40411`}, {260.`, 
2.40749`}, {265.`, 2.41679`}, {270.`, 2.42152`}, {275.`, 
2.40963`}, {280.`, 2.39891`}, {285.`, 2.39964`}, {290.`, 
2.39939`}, {295.`, 2.40453`}, {300.`, 2.40663`}, {305.`, 
2.41569`}, {310.`, 2.40495`}, {315.`, 2.40756`}, {320.`, 
2.41375`}, {325.`, 2.41212`}, {330.`, 2.41838`}, {335.`, 
2.41029`}, {340.`, 2.40475`}, {345.`, 2.40698`}, {350.`, 
2.41066`}, {355.`, 2.40286`}, {360.`, 2.40045`}, {365.`, 
2.38019`}, {370.`, 2.1133`}, {375.`, 2.74495`}, {380.`, 
2.44314`}, {385.`, 2.23574`}, {390.`, 2.26553`}, {395.`, 
2.28845`}, {400.`, 2.3039`}, {405.`, 2.32833`}, {410.`, 
2.35769`}, {415.`, 2.36831`}, {420.`, 2.38712`}, {425.`, 
2.39121`}, {430.`, 2.3947`}, {435.`, 2.39861`}, {440.`, 
2.40759`}, {445.`, 2.41661`}, {450.`, 2.41583`}, {455.`, 
2.41684`}, {460.`, 2.40925`}, {465.`, 2.40916`}, {470.`, 
2.41589`}, {475.`, 2.41347`}, {480.`, 2.40624`}, {485.`, 
2.40825`}, {490.`, 2.41021`}, {495.`, 2.40547`}, {500.`, 
2.41236`}, {505.`, 2.41382`}, {510.`, 2.40723`}, {515.`, 
2.40647`}, {520.`, 2.40802`}, {525.`, 2.41601`}, {530.`, 
2.4071`}, {535.`, 2.4085`}, {540.`, 2.41095`}, {545.`, 
2.38785`}, {550.`, 2.1242`}, {555.`, 2.74989`}, {560.`, 
2.47186`}, {565.`, 2.22649`}, {570.`, 2.25904`}, {575.`, 
2.27855`}, {580.`, 2.30019`}, {585.`, 2.31269`}, {590.`, 
2.33149`}, {595.`, 2.35533`}, {600.`, 2.37581`}, {605.`, 
2.38236`}, {610.`, 2.39662`}, {615.`, 2.38875`}, {620.`, 
2.3945`}, {625.`, 2.40292`}, {630.`, 2.41223`}, {635.`, 
2.41755`}, {640.`, 2.41581`}, {645.`, 2.42747`}, {650.`, 
2.42243`}, {655.`, 2.40486`}, {660.`, 2.41097`}, {665.`, 
2.41289`}, {670.`, 2.4112`}, {675.`, 2.41057`}, {680.`, 
2.40854`}, {685.`, 2.40255`}, {690.`, 2.40663`}, {695.`, 
2.41292`}, {700.`, 2.39958`}, {705.`, 2.40153`}, {710.`, 
2.41089`}, {715.`, 2.41834`}, {720.`, 2.41014`}, {725.`, 
2.38069`}, {730.`, 2.18214`}, {735.`, 2.78697`}, {740.`, 
2.43799`}, {745.`, 2.2292`}, {750.`, 2.2685`}, {755.`, 
2.27852`}, {760.`, 2.29429`}, {765.`, 2.31846`}, {770.`, 
2.33485`}, {775.`, 2.34926`}, {780.`, 2.36237`}, {785.`, 
2.37218`}, {790.`, 2.37895`}, {795.`, 2.38696`}, {800.`, 
2.39067`}, {805.`, 2.40635`}, {810.`, 2.40362`}, {815.`, 
2.408`}, {820.`, 2.40672`}, {825.`, 2.4003`}, {830.`, 
2.40356`}, {835.`, 2.40439`}, {840.`, 2.41256`}, {845.`, 
2.40369`}, {850.`, 2.40362`}, {855.`, 2.40254`}, {860.`, 
2.40808`}, {865.`, 2.41858`}, {870.`, 2.42083`}, {875.`, 
2.41221`}, {880.`, 2.41353`}, {885.`, 2.40919`}, {890.`, 
2.40225`}, {895.`, 2.40183`}, {900.`, 2.41031`}, {905.`, 
2.36319`}, {910.`, 2.232`}, {915.`, 2.83176`}, {920.`, 
2.40338`}, {925.`, 2.24156`}, {930.`, 2.26923`}, {935.`, 
2.27405`}, {940.`, 2.29832`}, {945.`, 2.32295`}, {950.`, 
2.34304`}, {955.`, 2.35416`}, {960.`, 2.36042`}, {965.`, 
2.37545`}, {970.`, 2.37944`}, {975.`, 2.38077`}, {980.`, 
2.38672`}, {985.`, 2.39831`}, {990.`, 2.40744`}, {995.`, 
2.41327`}, {1000.`, 2.4076`}, {1005.`, 2.41045`}, {1010.`, 
2.41492`}, {1015.`, 2.42123`}, {1020.`, 2.42311`}, {1025.`, 
2.41626`}, {1030.`, 2.40367`}, {1035.`, 2.4063`}, {1040.`, 
2.42103`}, {1045.`, 2.41064`}, {1050.`, 2.40684`}, {1055.`, 
2.40098`}, {1060.`, 2.41097`}, {1065.`, 2.41592`}, {1070.`, 
2.40849`}, {1075.`, 2.40616`}, {1080.`, 2.41021`}, {1085.`, 
2.36027`}, {1090.`, 2.27795`}, {1095.`, 2.84617`}, {1100.`, 
2.37269`}, {1105.`, 2.25954`}, {1110.`, 2.29005`}, {1115.`, 
2.29649`}, {1120.`, 2.30906`}, {1125.`, 2.32596`}, {1130.`, 
2.33398`}, {1135.`, 2.3494`}, {1140.`, 2.37214`}, {1145.`, 
2.38268`}, {1150.`, 2.39181`}, {1155.`, 2.39219`}, {1160.`, 
2.39735`}, {1165.`, 2.40887`}, {1170.`, 2.40433`}, {1175.`, 
2.40305`}, {1180.`, 2.41262`}, {1185.`, 2.40782`}, {1190.`, 
2.40641`}, {1195.`, 2.40956`}, {1200.`, 2.4138`}, {1205.`, 
2.42494`}, {1210.`, 2.41362`}, {1215.`, 2.40338`}, {1220.`, 
2.39176`}, {1225.`, 2.40127`}, {1230.`, 2.41093`}, {1235.`, 
2.41167`}, {1240.`, 2.41547`}, {1245.`, 2.41724`}, {1250.`, 
2.41734`}, {1255.`, 2.41807`}, {1260.`, 2.40711`}, {1265.`, 
2.32865`}, {1270.`, 2.33615`}, {1275.`, 2.83364`}, {1280.`, 
2.35782`}, {1285.`, 2.2653`}, {1290.`, 2.30087`}, {1295.`, 
2.30539`}, {1300.`, 2.30546`}, {1305.`, 2.32279`}, {1310.`, 
2.34521`}, {1315.`, 2.35093`}, {1320.`, 2.36876`}, {1325.`, 
2.38492`}, {1330.`, 2.38044`}, {1335.`, 2.38815`}, {1340.`, 
2.38348`}, {1345.`, 2.40065`}, {1350.`, 2.39982`}, {1355.`, 
2.39992`}, {1360.`, 2.4054`}, {1365.`, 2.40309`}, {1370.`, 
2.40594`}, {1375.`, 2.4014`}, {1380.`, 2.40763`}, {1385.`, 
2.40742`}, {1390.`, 2.40345`}, {1395.`, 2.41129`}, {1400.`, 
2.41493`}, {1405.`, 2.41004`}, {1410.`, 2.41289`}, {1415.`, 
2.41294`}, {1420.`, 2.4068`}, {1425.`, 2.4041`}, {1430.`, 
2.39989`}, {1435.`, 2.41382`}, {1440.`, 2.4151`}, {1445.`, 
2.28722`}, {1450.`, 2.41435`}, {1455.`, 2.8229`}, {1460.`, 
2.34602`}, {1465.`, 2.27485`}, {1470.`, 2.28696`}, {1475.`, 
2.30587`}, {1480.`, 2.32392`}, {1485.`, 2.33769`}, {1490.`, 
2.34829`}, {1495.`, 2.35833`}, {1500.`, 2.36606`}, {1505.`, 
2.38031`}, {1510.`, 2.3882`}, {1515.`, 2.38575`}, {1520.`, 
2.3876`}, {1525.`, 2.38859`}, {1530.`, 2.39528`}, {1535.`, 
2.40662`}, {1540.`, 2.40589`}, {1545.`, 2.3999`}, {1550.`, 
2.39553`}, {1555.`, 2.40459`}, {1560.`, 2.41215`}, {1565.`, 
2.41109`}, {1570.`, 2.40651`}, {1575.`, 2.41199`}, {1580.`, 
2.40756`}, {1585.`, 2.40943`}, {1590.`, 2.40304`}, {1595.`, 
2.40769`}, {1600.`, 2.40626`}, {1605.`, 2.41822`}, {1610.`, 
2.41579`}, {1615.`, 2.40967`}, {1620.`, 2.41079`}, {1625.`, 
2.27913`}, {1630.`, 2.49834`}, {1635.`, 2.79117`}, {1640.`, 
2.34607`}, {1645.`, 2.30948`}, {1650.`, 2.31606`}, {1655.`, 
2.31426`}, {1660.`, 2.32389`}, {1665.`, 2.33934`}, {1670.`, 
2.35389`}, {1675.`, 2.36893`}, {1680.`, 2.37683`}, {1685.`, 
2.38726`}, {1690.`, 2.37577`}, {1695.`, 2.38969`}, {1700.`, 
2.39511`}, {1705.`, 2.40145`}, {1710.`, 2.41432`}, {1715.`, 
2.4107`}, {1720.`, 2.40342`}, {1725.`, 2.39728`}, {1730.`, 
2.3995`}, {1735.`, 2.41101`}, {1740.`, 2.4087`}, {1745.`, 
2.40425`}, {1750.`, 2.41393`}, {1755.`, 2.41272`}, {1760.`, 
2.40541`}, {1765.`, 2.40436`}, {1770.`, 2.40444`}, {1775.`, 
2.41926`}, {1780.`, 2.41969`}, {1785.`, 2.4193`}, {1790.`, 
2.4009`}, {1795.`, 2.39214`}, {1800.`, 2.41367`}, {1805.`, 
2.2484`}, {1810.`, 2.59714`}, {1815.`, 2.76393`}, {1820.`, 
2.35331`}, {1825.`, 2.33172`}, {1830.`, 2.34277`}, {1835.`, 
2.33886`}, {1840.`, 2.34158`}, {1845.`, 2.3528`}, {1850.`, 
2.36269`}, {1855.`, 2.36324`}, {1860.`, 2.37877`}, {1865.`, 
2.38914`}, {1870.`, 2.39899`}, {1875.`, 2.41142`}, {1880.`, 
2.40601`}, {1885.`, 2.40194`}, {1890.`, 2.39789`}, {1895.`, 
2.39619`}, {1900.`, 2.40568`}, {1905.`, 2.40624`}, {1910.`, 
2.39888`}, {1915.`, 2.40384`}, {1920.`, 2.40937`}, {1925.`, 
2.40709`}, {1930.`, 2.3954`}, {1935.`, 2.41691`}, {1940.`, 
2.41117`}, {1945.`, 2.4113`}, {1950.`, 2.41505`}, {1955.`, 
2.41613`}, {1960.`, 2.39838`}, {1965.`, 2.41402`}, {1970.`, 
2.42415`}, {1975.`, 2.40659`}, {1980.`, 2.40548`}, {1985.`, 
2.21571`}, {1990.`, 2.65837`}, {1995.`, 2.73631`}, {2000.`, 
2.35978`}, {2005.`, 2.34484`}, {2010.`, 2.35112`}, {2015.`, 
2.35091`}, {2020.`, 2.35177`}, {2025.`, 2.368`}, {2030.`, 
2.36698`}, {2035.`, 2.36624`}, {2040.`, 2.37748`}, {2045.`, 
2.39053`}, {2050.`, 2.40695`}, {2055.`, 2.3986`}, {2060.`, 
2.39201`}, {2065.`, 2.39138`}, {2070.`, 2.4025`}, {2075.`, 
2.39562`}, {2080.`, 2.39907`}, {2085.`, 2.40644`}, {2090.`, 
2.40431`}, {2095.`, 2.40976`}, {2100.`, 2.41335`}, {2105.`, 
2.40873`}, {2110.`, 2.41339`}, {2115.`, 2.40891`}, {2120.`, 
2.40193`}, {2125.`, 2.40877`}, {2130.`, 2.40299`}, {2135.`, 
2.40932`}, {2140.`, 2.41331`}, {2145.`, 2.41337`}, {2150.`, 
2.41622`}, {2155.`, 2.41557`}, {2160.`, 2.39431`}, {2165.`, 
2.21113`}, {2170.`, 2.7475`}, {2175.`, 2.71327`}, {2180.`, 
2.36883`}, {2185.`, 2.36859`}, {2190.`, 2.36066`}, {2195.`, 
2.35285`}, {2200.`, 2.36043`}, {2205.`, 2.36718`}, {2210.`, 
2.36877`}, {2215.`, 2.379`}, {2220.`, 2.38187`}, {2225.`, 
2.3843`}, {2230.`, 2.38609`}, {2235.`, 2.39319`}, {2240.`, 
2.39669`}, {2245.`, 2.40071`}, {2250.`, 2.40816`}, {2255.`, 
2.40158`}, {2260.`, 2.40025`}, {2265.`, 2.40674`}, {2270.`, 
2.40415`}, {2275.`, 2.40082`}, {2280.`, 2.40433`}, {2285.`, 
2.40276`}, {2290.`, 2.40646`}, {2295.`, 2.4118`}, {2300.`, 
2.41148`}, {2305.`, 2.41281`}, {2310.`, 2.41068`}, {2315.`, 
2.4124`}, {2320.`, 2.41638`}, {2325.`, 2.40889`}, {2330.`, 
2.40997`}, {2335.`, 2.41283`}, {2340.`, 2.40355`}, {2345.`, 
2.20563`}, {2350.`, 2.81693`}, {2355.`, 2.64497`}, {2360.`, 
2.38628`}, {2365.`, 2.38358`}, {2370.`, 2.35984`}, {2375.`, 
2.3353`}, {2380.`, 2.33928`}, {2385.`, 2.3755`}, {2390.`, 
2.3937`}, {2395.`, 2.40242`}, {2400.`, 2.40019`}, {2405.`, 
2.40045`}, {2410.`, 2.40662`}, {2415.`, 2.39452`}, {2420.`, 
2.40121`}, {2425.`, 2.40519`}, {2430.`, 2.41115`}, {2435.`, 
2.40907`}, {2440.`, 2.41081`}, {2445.`, 2.41106`}, {2450.`, 
2.4048`}, {2455.`, 2.40557`}, {2460.`, 2.41594`}, {2465.`, 
2.41154`}, {2470.`, 2.40212`}, {2475.`, 2.40306`}, {2480.`, 
2.40882`}, {2485.`, 2.40885`}, {2490.`, 2.40957`}, {2495.`, 
2.40612`}, {2500.`, 2.41516`}, {2505.`, 2.41002`}, {2510.`, 
2.4051`}, {2515.`, 2.40895`}, {2520.`, 2.3899`}, {2525.`, 
2.22593`}, {2530.`, 2.89478`}, {2535.`, 2.63094`}, {2540.`, 
2.391`}, {2545.`, 2.38988`}, {2550.`, 2.38889`}, {2555.`, 
2.37609`}, {2560.`, 2.37363`}, {2565.`, 2.38331`}, {2570.`, 
2.38947`}, {2575.`, 2.39065`}, {2580.`, 2.40342`}, {2585.`, 
2.40463`}, {2590.`, 2.40705`}, {2595.`, 2.40622`}, {2600.`, 
2.4034`}, {2605.`, 2.40399`}, {2610.`, 2.40678`}, {2615.`, 
2.40212`}, {2620.`, 2.40608`}, {2625.`, 2.40504`}, {2630.`, 
2.40786`}, {2635.`, 2.40423`}, {2640.`, 2.41536`}, {2645.`, 
2.40555`}, {2650.`, 2.4112`}, {2655.`, 2.40765`}, {2660.`, 
2.41189`}, {2665.`, 2.41341`}, {2670.`, 2.40949`}, {2675.`, 
2.41195`}, {2680.`, 2.40808`}, {2685.`, 2.40592`}, {2690.`, 
2.40878`}, {2695.`, 2.4076`}, {2700.`, 2.38287`}, {2705.`, 
2.26775`}, {2710.`, 2.9191`}, {2715.`, 2.58594`}, {2720.`, 
2.40379`}, {2725.`, 2.40323`}, {2730.`, 2.39013`}, {2735.`, 
2.38552`}, {2740.`, 2.38561`}, {2745.`, 2.39306`}, {2750.`, 
2.39949`}, {2755.`, 2.39865`}, {2760.`, 2.39942`}, {2765.`, 
2.40954`}, {2770.`, 2.40731`}, {2775.`, 2.40041`}, {2780.`, 
2.41413`}, {2785.`, 2.41801`}, {2790.`, 2.40736`}, {2795.`, 
2.40968`}, {2800.`, 2.40746`}, {2805.`, 2.40076`}, {2810.`, 
2.40145`}, {2815.`, 2.4018`}, {2820.`, 2.41083`}, {2825.`, 
2.41527`}, {2830.`, 2.40168`}, {2835.`, 2.40068`}, {2840.`, 
2.41038`}, {2845.`, 2.42144`}, {2850.`, 2.41792`}, {2855.`, 
2.40315`}, {2860.`, 2.41036`}, {2865.`, 2.41057`}, {2870.`, 
2.40902`}, {2875.`, 2.39517`}, {2880.`, 2.36328`}, {2885.`, 
2.30125`}, {2890.`, 2.94511`}, {2895.`, 2.56359`}, {2900.`, 
2.41223`}, {2905.`, 2.41682`}, {2910.`, 2.39815`}, {2915.`, 
2.39672`}, {2920.`, 2.39468`}, {2925.`, 2.39092`}, {2930.`, 
2.39251`}, {2935.`, 2.39373`}, {2940.`, 2.40379`}, {2945.`, 
2.4021`}, {2950.`, 2.40217`}, {2955.`, 2.40567`}, {2960.`, 
2.41147`}, {2965.`, 2.4039`}, {2970.`, 2.40519`}, {2975.`, 
2.40664`}, {2980.`, 2.4033`}, {2985.`, 2.41044`}, {2990.`, 
2.41235`}, {2995.`, 2.41487`}, {3000.`, 2.40163`}, {3005.`, 
2.40508`}, {3010.`, 2.41392`}, {3015.`, 2.4178`}, {3020.`, 
2.41705`}, {3025.`, 2.41934`}, {3030.`, 2.41014`}, {3035.`, 
2.39937`}, {3040.`, 2.40823`}, {3045.`, 2.40952`}, {3050.`, 
2.40438`}, {3055.`, 2.40994`}, {3060.`, 2.34276`}, {3065.`, 
2.36424`}, {3070.`, 2.94258`}, {3075.`, 2.52957`}, {3080.`, 
2.42529`}, {3085.`, 2.41893`}, {3090.`, 2.41232`}, {3095.`, 
2.41014`}, {3100.`, 2.3915`}, {3105.`, 2.38849`}, {3110.`, 
2.39132`}, {3115.`, 2.39991`}, {3120.`, 2.40575`}, {3125.`, 
2.40973`}, {3130.`, 2.40302`}, {3135.`, 2.40056`}, {3140.`, 
2.41163`}, {3145.`, 2.40793`}, {3150.`, 2.40918`}, {3155.`, 
2.40973`}, {3160.`, 2.41199`}, {3165.`, 2.40405`}, {3170.`, 
2.40842`}, {3175.`, 2.40664`}, {3180.`, 2.4034`}, {3185.`, 
2.40243`}, {3190.`, 2.40928`}, {3195.`, 2.41602`}, {3200.`, 
2.42781`}, {3205.`, 2.4138`}, {3210.`, 2.39347`}, {3215.`, 
2.39687`}, {3220.`, 2.41502`}, {3225.`, 2.41708`}, {3230.`, 
2.41123`}, {3235.`, 2.40532`}, {3240.`, 2.32977`}, {3245.`, 
2.43944`}, {3250.`, 2.91894`}, {3255.`, 2.5104`}, {3260.`, 
2.42035`}, {3265.`, 2.42273`}, {3270.`, 2.40312`}, {3275.`, 
2.39481`}, {3280.`, 2.39523`}, {3285.`, 2.39197`}, {3290.`, 
2.40478`}, {3295.`, 2.39922`}, {3300.`, 2.4015`}, {3305.`, 
2.4`}, {3310.`, 2.40691`}, {3315.`, 2.40598`}, {3320.`, 
2.39695`}, {3325.`, 2.40378`}, {3330.`, 2.40616`}, {3335.`, 
2.40051`}, {3340.`, 2.3987`}, {3345.`, 2.40107`}, {3350.`, 
2.41592`}, {3355.`, 2.42841`}, {3360.`, 2.4149`}, {3365.`, 
2.41096`}, {3370.`, 2.40874`}, {3375.`, 2.39608`}, {3380.`, 
2.39828`}, {3385.`, 2.40374`}, {3390.`, 2.41647`}, {3395.`, 
2.41195`}, {3400.`, 2.4102`}, {3405.`, 2.40823`}, {3410.`, 
2.40458`}, {3415.`, 2.40991`}, {3420.`, 2.29829`}, {3425.`, 
2.52284`}, {3430.`, 2.90159`}, {3435.`, 2.49328`}, {3440.`, 
2.42777`}, {3445.`, 2.41665`}, {3450.`, 2.41036`}, {3455.`, 
2.40293`}, {3460.`, 2.39496`}, {3465.`, 2.3923`}, {3470.`, 
2.39634`}, {3475.`, 2.39252`}, {3480.`, 2.39638`}, {3485.`, 
2.40565`}, {3490.`, 2.4058`}, {3495.`, 2.40823`}, {3500.`, 
2.40689`}, {3505.`, 2.41229`}, {3510.`, 2.41117`}, {3515.`, 
2.42023`}, {3520.`, 2.41173`}, {3525.`, 2.40385`}, {3530.`, 
2.40574`}, {3535.`, 2.40931`}, {3540.`, 2.41006`}, {3545.`, 
2.41316`}, {3550.`, 2.40941`}, {3555.`, 2.4121`}, {3560.`, 
2.41232`}, {3565.`, 2.4144`}, {3570.`, 2.40649`}, {3575.`, 
2.41175`}, {3580.`, 2.4164`}, {3585.`, 2.40175`}, {3590.`, 
2.40216`}, {3595.`, 2.41338`}, {3600.`, 2.2923`}, {3605.`, 
2.59634`}, {3610.`, 2.87715`}, {3615.`, 2.4852`}, {3620.`, 
2.4326`}, {3625.`, 2.42894`}, {3630.`, 2.40861`}, {3635.`, 
2.40604`}, {3640.`, 2.39888`}, {3645.`, 2.40756`}, {3650.`, 
2.40069`}, {3655.`, 2.39663`}, {3660.`, 2.40353`}, {3665.`, 
2.40158`}, {3670.`, 2.40386`}, {3675.`, 2.40449`}, {3680.`, 
2.41445`}, {3685.`, 2.41621`}, {3690.`, 2.42335`}, {3695.`, 
2.42293`}, {3700.`, 2.4005`}, {3705.`, 2.41192`}, {3710.`, 
2.39912`}, {3715.`, 2.40205`}, {3720.`, 2.41158`}, {3725.`, 
2.4092`}, {3730.`, 2.4028`}, {3735.`, 2.41115`}, {3740.`, 
2.4083`}, {3745.`, 2.41054`}, {3750.`, 2.41284`}, {3755.`, 
2.41464`}, {3760.`, 2.40582`}, {3765.`, 2.41143`}, {3770.`, 
2.41059`}, {3775.`, 2.40402`}, {3780.`, 2.26531`}, {3785.`, 
2.65256`}, {3790.`, 2.8446`}, {3795.`, 2.47815`}, {3800.`, 
2.44222`}, {3805.`, 2.43105`}, {3810.`, 2.40871`}, {3815.`, 
2.39964`}, {3820.`, 2.39852`}, {3825.`, 2.40385`}, {3830.`, 
2.3995`}, {3835.`, 2.40486`}, {3840.`, 2.40644`}, {3845.`, 
2.41043`}, {3850.`, 2.41343`}, {3855.`, 2.40286`}, {3860.`, 
2.40778`}, {3865.`, 2.40444`}, {3870.`, 2.40409`}, {3875.`, 
2.40264`}, {3880.`, 2.40493`}, {3885.`, 2.41227`}, {3890.`, 
2.4129`}, {3895.`, 2.41205`}, {3900.`, 2.40811`}, {3905.`, 
2.41428`}, {3910.`, 2.41322`}, {3915.`, 2.40535`}, {3920.`, 
2.40699`}, {3925.`, 2.40382`}, {3930.`, 2.411`}, {3935.`, 
2.41657`}, {3940.`, 2.41913`}, {3945.`, 2.40128`}, {3950.`, 
2.40489`}, {3955.`, 2.3995`}, {3960.`, 2.27063`}, {3965.`, 
2.74078`}, {3970.`, 2.79773`}, {3975.`, 2.4763`}, {3980.`, 
2.45039`}, {3985.`, 2.44845`}, {3990.`, 2.41457`}, {3995.`, 
2.4007`}, {4000.`, 2.40374`}, {4005.`, 2.39614`}, {4010.`, 
2.38649`}, {4015.`, 2.40103`}, {4020.`, 2.40973`}, {4025.`, 
2.40131`}, {4030.`, 2.40685`}, {4035.`, 2.4087`}, {4040.`, 
2.41491`}, {4045.`, 2.40158`}, {4050.`, 2.40683`}, {4055.`, 
2.40812`}, {4060.`, 2.40887`}, {4065.`, 2.42845`}, {4070.`, 
2.42424`}, {4075.`, 2.40928`}, {4080.`, 2.40596`}, {4085.`, 
2.40689`}, {4090.`, 2.41005`}, {4095.`, 2.40936`}, {4100.`, 
2.41679`}, {4105.`, 2.41136`}, {4110.`, 2.4038`}, {4115.`, 
2.40753`}, {4120.`, 2.40193`}, {4125.`, 2.40654`}, {4130.`, 
2.41734`}, {4135.`, 2.40446`}, {4140.`, 2.24692`}, {4145.`, 
2.8008`}, {4150.`, 2.7591`}, {4155.`, 2.47163`}, {4160.`, 
2.44441`}, {4165.`, 2.42747`}, {4170.`, 2.41589`}, {4175.`, 
2.40688`}, {4180.`, 2.40853`}, {4185.`, 2.39945`}, {4190.`, 
2.4076`}, {4195.`, 2.40163`}, {4200.`, 2.409`}, {4205.`, 
2.39929`}, {4210.`, 2.40303`}, {4215.`, 2.41232`}, {4220.`, 
2.40954`}, {4225.`, 2.41337`}, {4230.`, 2.40692`}, {4235.`, 
2.40917`}, {4240.`, 2.4121`}, {4245.`, 2.41584`}, {4250.`, 
2.41113`}, {4255.`, 2.41165`}, {4260.`, 2.4092`}, {4265.`, 
2.40762`}, {4270.`, 2.40712`}, {4275.`, 2.40544`}, {4280.`, 
2.41564`}, {4285.`, 2.40238`}, {4290.`, 2.40514`}, {4295.`, 
2.40809`}, {4300.`, 2.41179`}, {4305.`, 2.4129`}, {4310.`, 
2.40504`}, {4315.`, 2.39306`}, {4320.`, 2.26204`}, {4325.`, 
2.88208`}, {4330.`, 2.70085`}, {4335.`, 2.46317`}, {4340.`, 
2.44685`}, {4345.`, 2.42361`}, {4350.`, 2.41842`}, {4355.`, 
2.4091`}, {4360.`, 2.40422`}, {4365.`, 2.40463`}, {4370.`, 
2.40324`}, {4375.`, 2.40321`}, {4380.`, 2.40004`}, {4385.`, 
2.40133`}, {4390.`, 2.40408`}, {4395.`, 2.40832`}, {4400.`, 
2.41216`}, {4405.`, 2.40196`}, {4410.`, 2.40989`}, {4415.`, 
2.41381`}, {4420.`, 2.41805`}, {4425.`, 2.40691`}, {4430.`, 
2.40226`}, {4435.`, 2.4149`}, {4440.`, 2.41781`}, {4445.`, 
2.41866`}, {4450.`, 2.40351`}, {4455.`, 2.40178`}, {4460.`, 
2.39586`}, {4465.`, 2.41188`}, {4470.`, 2.41342`}, {4475.`, 
2.41997`}, {4480.`, 2.40395`}, {4485.`, 2.39722`}, {4490.`, 
2.41563`}, {4495.`, 2.39953`}, {4500.`, 2.30335`}, {4505.`, 
2.91313`}, {4510.`, 2.63888`}, {4515.`, 2.45092`}, {4520.`, 
2.44303`}, {4525.`, 2.42815`}, {4530.`, 2.42271`}, {4535.`, 
2.40698`}, {4540.`, 2.40051`}, {4545.`, 2.40771`}, {4550.`, 
2.41056`}, {4555.`, 2.40327`}, {4560.`, 2.415`}, {4565.`, 
2.40637`}, {4570.`, 2.40677`}, {4575.`, 2.40188`}, {4580.`, 
2.39946`}, {4585.`, 2.39933`}, {4590.`, 2.40898`}, {4595.`, 
2.41212`}, {4600.`, 2.40289`}, {4605.`, 2.41021`}, {4610.`, 
2.40574`}, {4615.`, 2.40609`}, {4620.`, 2.41362`}, {4625.`, 
2.4118`}, {4630.`, 2.40931`}, {4635.`, 2.402`}, {4640.`, 
2.41577`}, {4645.`, 2.41723`}, {4650.`, 2.40756`}, {4655.`, 
2.40962`}, {4660.`, 2.40811`}, {4665.`, 2.40208`}, {4670.`, 
2.41068`}, {4675.`, 2.38711`}, {4680.`, 2.32236`}, {4685.`, 
2.91923`}, {4690.`, 2.60809`}, {4695.`, 2.4544`}, {4700.`, 
2.44075`}, {4705.`, 2.40827`}, {4710.`, 2.4014`}, {4715.`, 
2.40783`}, {4720.`, 2.39529`}, {4725.`, 2.40265`}, {4730.`, 
2.39976`}, {4735.`, 2.40475`}, {4740.`, 2.40885`}, {4745.`, 
2.41369`}, {4750.`, 2.40116`}, {4755.`, 2.40206`}, {4760.`, 
2.40503`}, {4765.`, 2.39698`}, {4770.`, 2.40121`}, {4775.`, 
2.40786`}, {4780.`, 2.41506`}, {4785.`, 2.41421`}, {4790.`, 
2.41095`}, {4795.`, 2.41327`}, {4800.`, 2.40995`}, {4805.`, 
2.40527`}, {4810.`, 2.40721`}, {4815.`, 2.40425`}, {4820.`, 
2.41059`}, {4825.`, 2.40782`}, {4830.`, 2.41545`}, {4835.`, 
2.41219`}, {4840.`, 2.3951`}, {4845.`, 2.40732`}, {4850.`, 
2.41484`}, {4855.`, 2.36988`}, {4860.`, 2.37495`}, {4865.`, 
2.93139`}, {4870.`, 2.56992`}, {4875.`, 2.44922`}, {4880.`, 
2.44616`}, {4885.`, 2.42731`}, {4890.`, 2.41868`}, {4895.`, 
2.40456`}, {4900.`, 2.40006`}, {4905.`, 2.40317`}, {4910.`, 
2.41277`}, {4915.`, 2.40633`}, {4920.`, 2.40256`}, {4925.`, 
2.40916`}, {4930.`, 2.41088`}, {4935.`, 2.40716`}, {4940.`, 
2.40644`}, {4945.`, 2.40193`}, {4950.`, 2.39792`}, {4955.`, 
2.41379`}, {4960.`, 2.4091`}, {4965.`, 2.40918`}, {4970.`, 
2.41345`}, {4975.`, 2.40496`}, {4980.`, 2.41383`}, {4985.`, 
2.4132`}, {4990.`, 2.41174`}, {4995.`, 2.40417`}, {5000.`, 
2.40694`}, {5005.`, 2.4083`}, {5010.`, 2.40923`}, {5015.`, 
2.41452`}, {5020.`, 2.40601`}, {5025.`, 2.40756`}, {5030.`, 
2.40644`}, {5035.`, 2.35496`}, {5040.`, 2.43043`}, {5045.`, 
2.93189`}, {5050.`, 2.54727`}, {5055.`, 2.45738`}, {5060.`, 
2.44667`}, {5065.`, 2.42822`}, {5070.`, 2.41577`}, {5075.`, 
2.40941`}, {5080.`, 2.40465`}, {5085.`, 2.40363`}, {5090.`, 
2.40243`}, {5095.`, 2.40618`}, {5100.`, 2.40537`}, {5105.`, 
2.41344`}, {5110.`, 2.40973`}, {5115.`, 2.41427`}, {5120.`, 
2.40947`}, {5125.`, 2.40572`}, {5130.`, 2.40376`}, {5135.`, 
2.40504`}, {5140.`, 2.41684`}, {5145.`, 2.41183`}, {5150.`, 
2.40915`}, {5155.`, 2.41705`}, {5160.`, 2.41147`}, {5165.`, 
2.4127`}, {5170.`, 2.40964`}, {5175.`, 2.40996`}, {5180.`, 
2.3947`}, {5185.`, 2.38947`}, {5190.`, 2.41189`}, {5195.`, 
2.41298`}, {5200.`, 2.4152`}, {5205.`, 2.41317`}, {5210.`, 
2.41602`}, {5215.`, 2.33882`}, {5220.`, 2.49707`}, {5225.`, 
2.9012`}, {5230.`, 2.52914`}, {5235.`, 2.46032`}, {5240.`, 
2.44287`}, {5245.`, 2.42767`}, {5250.`, 2.41828`}, {5255.`, 
2.41346`}, {5260.`, 2.40736`}, {5265.`, 2.42005`}, {5270.`, 
2.41399`}, {5275.`, 2.40065`}, {5280.`, 2.4109`}, {5285.`, 
2.40704`}, {5290.`, 2.41365`}, {5295.`, 2.40536`}, {5300.`, 
2.4136`}, {5305.`, 2.4116`}, {5310.`, 2.41037`}, {5315.`, 
2.4175`}, {5320.`, 2.41461`}, {5325.`, 2.41399`}, {5330.`, 
2.40139`}, {5335.`, 2.4043`}, {5340.`, 2.41749`}, {5345.`, 
2.40446`}, {5350.`, 2.39904`}, {5355.`, 2.40398`}, {5360.`, 
2.4044`}, {5365.`, 2.40839`}, {5370.`, 2.42133`}, {5375.`, 
2.42036`}, {5380.`, 2.40643`}, {5385.`, 2.41151`}, {5390.`, 
2.40711`}, {5395.`, 2.31057`}, {5400.`, 2.57709`}, {5405.`, 
2.86397`}, {5410.`, 2.50812`}, {5415.`, 2.45353`}, {5420.`, 
2.44748`}, {5425.`, 2.42939`}, {5430.`, 2.41908`}, {5435.`, 
2.41071`}, {5440.`, 2.40854`}, {5445.`, 2.41516`}, {5450.`, 
2.40418`}, {5455.`, 2.40728`}, {5460.`, 2.40712`}, {5465.`, 
2.41087`}, {5470.`, 2.40335`}, {5475.`, 2.40573`}, {5480.`, 
2.41084`}, {5485.`, 2.41015`}, {5490.`, 2.40878`}, {5495.`, 
2.40723`}, {5500.`, 2.40844`}, {5505.`, 2.41467`}, {5510.`, 
2.40522`}, {5515.`, 2.41144`}, {5520.`, 2.42059`}, {5525.`, 
2.40585`}, {5530.`, 2.41099`}, {5535.`, 2.40533`}, {5540.`, 
2.40622`}, {5545.`, 2.40592`}, {5550.`, 2.41787`}, {5555.`, 
2.41153`}, {5560.`, 2.40726`}, {5565.`, 2.40419`}, {5570.`, 
2.40416`}, {5575.`, 2.29684`}, {5580.`, 2.64283`}, {5585.`, 
2.83475`}, {5590.`, 2.50427`}, {5595.`, 2.45912`}, {5600.`, 
2.44144`}, {5605.`, 2.42377`}, {5610.`, 2.42402`}, {5615.`, 
2.41795`}, {5620.`, 2.41199`}, {5625.`, 2.41061`}, {5630.`, 
2.39882`}, {5635.`, 2.39689`}, {5640.`, 2.40341`}, {5645.`, 
2.41595`}, {5650.`, 2.41228`}, {5655.`, 2.40579`}, {5660.`, 
2.40817`}, {5665.`, 2.40579`}, {5670.`, 2.41678`}, {5675.`, 
2.41472`}, {5680.`, 2.41182`}, {5685.`, 2.41665`}, {5690.`, 
2.41586`}, {5695.`, 2.4121`}, {5700.`, 2.4114`}, {5705.`, 
2.40658`}, {5710.`, 2.41569`}, {5715.`, 2.41455`}, {5720.`, 
2.4109`}, {5725.`, 2.40737`}, {5730.`, 2.40026`}, {5735.`, 
2.40638`}, {5740.`, 2.41058`}, {5745.`, 2.40661`}, {5750.`, 
2.4088`}, {5755.`, 2.28851`}, {5760.`, 2.70645`}, {5765.`, 
2.79447`}, {5770.`, 2.49296`}, {5775.`, 2.45857`}, {5780.`, 
2.44645`}, {5785.`, 2.43097`}, {5790.`, 2.41662`}, {5795.`, 
2.4028`}, {5800.`, 2.40856`}, {5805.`, 2.40988`}, {5810.`, 
2.40615`}, {5815.`, 2.40563`}, {5820.`, 2.41224`}, {5825.`, 
2.41172`}, {5830.`, 2.41047`}, {5835.`, 2.40898`}, {5840.`, 
2.40564`}, {5845.`, 2.40873`}, {5850.`, 2.40644`}, {5855.`, 
2.40928`}, {5860.`, 2.40283`}, {5865.`, 2.40961`}, {5870.`, 
2.41159`}, {5875.`, 2.40477`}, {5880.`, 2.4069`}, {5885.`, 
2.41395`}, {5890.`, 2.41438`}, {5895.`, 2.41253`}, {5900.`, 
2.40618`}, {5905.`, 2.40497`}, {5910.`, 2.4047`}, {5915.`, 
2.4133`}, {5920.`, 2.41568`}, {5925.`, 2.40676`}, {5930.`, 
2.40654`}, {5935.`, 2.28086`}, {5940.`, 2.74798`}, {5945.`, 
2.75153`}, {5950.`, 2.47613`}, {5955.`, 2.45717`}, {5960.`, 
2.44017`}, {5965.`, 2.42128`}, {5970.`, 2.4109`}, {5975.`, 
2.41131`}, {5980.`, 2.40572`}, {5985.`, 2.40885`}, {5990.`, 
2.41398`}, {5995.`, 2.40948`}, {6000.`, 2.40204`}, {6005.`, 
2.40505`}, {6010.`, 2.40304`}, {6015.`, 2.41209`}, {6020.`, 
2.41467`}, {6025.`, 2.40861`}, {6030.`, 2.41332`}, {6035.`, 
2.41125`}, {6040.`, 2.41134`}, {6045.`, 2.40546`}, {6050.`, 
2.40309`}, {6055.`, 2.4102`}, {6060.`, 2.4083`}, {6065.`, 
2.40749`}, {6070.`, 2.41332`}, {6075.`, 2.41385`}, {6080.`, 
2.40465`}, {6085.`, 2.40853`}, {6090.`, 2.41537`}, {6095.`, 
2.40803`}, {6100.`, 2.40722`}, {6105.`, 2.40658`}, {6110.`, 
2.39967`}, {6115.`, 2.27789`}, {6120.`, 2.79025`}, {6125.`, 
2.72298`}, {6130.`, 2.47585`}, {6135.`, 2.45658`}, {6140.`, 
2.4421`}, {6145.`, 2.42512`}, {6150.`, 2.41549`}, {6155.`, 
2.40671`}, {6160.`, 2.41147`}, {6165.`, 2.41109`}, {6170.`, 
2.40714`}, {6175.`, 2.40616`}, {6180.`, 2.40487`}, {6185.`, 
2.40899`}, {6190.`, 2.40481`}, {6195.`, 2.40886`}, {6200.`, 
2.40437`}, {6205.`, 2.40808`}, {6210.`, 2.40414`}, {6215.`, 
2.41274`}, {6220.`, 2.4073`}, {6225.`, 2.4069`}, {6230.`, 
2.41265`}, {6235.`, 2.41384`}, {6240.`, 2.41199`}, {6245.`, 
2.40847`}, {6250.`, 2.41203`}, {6255.`, 2.40707`}, {6260.`, 
2.41111`}, {6265.`, 2.41438`}, {6270.`, 2.40149`}, {6275.`, 
2.40943`}, {6280.`, 2.40566`}, {6285.`, 2.40602`}, {6290.`, 
2.39158`}, {6295.`, 2.28929`}, {6300.`, 2.8602`}, {6305.`, 
2.66258`}, {6310.`, 2.46982`}, {6315.`, 2.45534`}, {6320.`, 
2.44041`}, {6325.`, 2.42411`}, {6330.`, 2.41174`}, {6335.`, 
2.41385`}, {6340.`, 2.41557`}, {6345.`, 2.40415`}, {6350.`, 
2.40414`}, {6355.`, 2.40665`}, {6360.`, 2.40593`}, {6365.`, 
2.40468`}, {6370.`, 2.4087`}, {6375.`, 2.40668`}, {6380.`, 
2.40482`}, {6385.`, 2.4102`}, {6390.`, 2.41138`}, {6395.`, 
2.40986`}, {6400.`, 2.41754`}, {6405.`, 2.41386`}, {6410.`, 
2.40579`}, {6415.`, 2.41131`}, {6420.`, 2.41011`}, {6425.`, 
2.41018`}, {6430.`, 2.40763`}, {6435.`, 2.412`}, {6440.`, 
2.40158`}, {6445.`, 2.40563`}, {6450.`, 2.41275`}, {6455.`, 
2.40791`}, {6460.`, 2.41374`}, {6465.`, 2.40603`}, {6470.`, 
2.39006`}, {6475.`, 2.30875`}, {6480.`, 2.87174`}, {6485.`, 
2.63457`}, {6490.`, 2.47627`}, {6495.`, 2.45683`}, {6500.`, 
2.4416`}, {6505.`, 2.42899`}, {6510.`, 2.41854`}, {6515.`, 
2.41043`}, {6520.`, 2.4094`}, {6525.`, 2.40516`}, {6530.`, 
2.40346`}, {6535.`, 2.40558`}};
```

Comment: You could try `LowpassFilter`. For example, with `y = data[[1 ;; 400, 2]]` (to see better) and `Manipulate[LowpassFilter[y, t] // ListLinePlot, {t, 0, 3}]`, you can see that `t=0.375` is not a too bad choice (I got rid of the $x$ values so of course you should compensate for that).

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible somehow to filter these spikes?

In that question "filter" can be interpreted in several ways. Instead of signal filtering (used in the previous answers) you can identify and remove the outliers.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/OutlierIdentifiers.m"]

(* This finds the outliers positions. *)
otlPos = OutlierPosition[data[[All, 2]], SPLUSQuartileIdentifierParameters];

(* Plot the data in blue and the outliers in red. *)
Show[ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[data[[otlPos]], PlotStyle -> {Red}]]
```

[image]

```
(* Plot the data with the outliers removed. *)
ListLinePlot[data[[Complement[Range[Length[data]], otlPos]]], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You might try a "moving median".  Unfortunately the decision for an optimal window width is "I'll know it when I see it" kinda thing.  In other words, it takes subject matter expertise and restraint.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[{data[[n, 1]], Median[data[[n - ww ;; n + ww, 2]]]},
   {n, ww + 1, Length[data] - ww}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All],
 {{ww, 2, "Window width"}, 2, 200, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Moving median and window width 2]

[image: Moving median and window width 130]

Answer (score 3):

How about a running median filter?

```
With[{
   time = Median /@ Partition[data[[All, 1]], 5, 1],
   ampl = Median /@ Partition[data[[All, 2]], 5, 1]}, 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{time, ampl}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Beat me by 30 seconds!